# How can I search for text files that do NOT contain a word?

Tags: linux, search, regex, grep

I need to be able to search a directory for all files that do not contain a certain word. My issue with my approaches so far is that they return every line of every file that does not contain the word. I just need a list of files that don't contain it.

Is there a program that does this? I prefer windows, but I also can use linux commands if you have one. I thought about grep -v, but this ends up printing out every lien of every file in a large directory (since most lines do not contain the phrase). I just need the file names (but contents searched).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl:dr:

```
grep -rIL searchword
```

According to [the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> **-R, -r, --recursive**
>
> Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
>
> **-L, --files-without-match**
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match.
>
> **-I**
>
> Process a binary file as if it did not contain matching data; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=without-match option.

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick. I had to do a more complicated command, but -L is the magic here.